# Styling pictures and their captions

Tags: graphics, captions, minipage

I need to insert some vector-drawn chemical structures into my document and want the figures to look similar to [those](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVWya.jpg). How do I restyle the caption boxes (e.g. turn the background grey and write Fig. 1 in bold)? I would also like to put a vertical line between the pictures. Can someone help me out?

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Coumarins}
    \end{minipage}~
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Furocoumarins}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

You can use the attached picture as `Coumarins.pdf` and `Furocoumarins.pdf`.

Comment: You can load the `caption` package and use the `\captionsetup` command. The problem with your question is that this is a far from complete or working example which includes graphics most users here won't have.

Comment: Appreciate that! Will try to do so. The question is not in graphics - you can take them for a simple pdf- or other vector formatted picture.

Comment: @Rubisko  please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=red,slc=off}
\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!50,linecolor=blue!50]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4-landscape.pdf}
            \caption{text}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!50,linecolor=blue!50]
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a4-landscape.pdf}
        \end{mdframed}
        \caption{text}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```